# Veeam extract utility for test passwords

Tags: powershell, veeam

I’m using the extract utility for test all the password of encrypted jobs and it work well. Just a problem when the password contain a double quotes (“).
I pass the good password but it seem that the extract utlity fails when we used password with double quote.

The main command i use is that one : .\Extract.exe -dir $full_dir -password $mdp

I got the error message “Password is incorrect”

obviously I already have verified the password and he is correct.

Does anyone have an idea ? or do i have to change all the password that contain a double quote ?

Comment: Make sure the double quote is the right double quote. There are [several](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) that look the same, but aren't. Too many editors autoformat quotes, so be sure this isn't the case.

Comment: Good idea but no, i tried to go by command line and type character by character and it's not working either

Comment: You probably need to escape the double-quote with some character. Could be a backslash or a caret `^` maybe, unfortunately I couldn't find anything on the documentation about that..